# Accented Character displaying in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I am getting some foreign language/accented words in JSON response. (eg.: `matelass&eacute;`, `d&eacute;cor`), this should be displayed as: `matelassé` and `décor`).

How should I handle this in my Swift app while displaying these words on label?

Also, these are not only two words, there are many more such words. So expecting a generic way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will have a look at it. Also, I don't know much about stack overflow. So, whatever you updated/edited in my question will it appear automatically (the corrected version of question) to all the people or do I have to approve it ?

Comment: Hi, Yes your answer actually helped me. but i don't know how to vote for your "duplicate mark comment". where and how can I vote for your comment? Thanks!